# Joomla stripping out #usemap

Tags: joomla, tinymce

I have a map inside a TinyMCE editor in Joomla 3, and it seems like when it is saved Joomla is messing with the html.  I just want no filtering or anything.

So this is the HTML I enter:

```
<img class="mapper noborder" 
     height="410" 
     id="Map_of_North_America" 
     name="Map_of_North_America" 
     src="/images/State Maps/Map_of_US_web_2014(1).png" 
     style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" 
     usemap="#m_Map_of_North_America" width="476" />
```

and this is what Joomla saves:

```
<img class="mapper noborder" 
     src="images/State Maps/Map_of_US_web_2014(1).png" 
     width="476" 
     height="410" 
     name="Map_of_North_America" 
     style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" />
```

It removes the `id`, as well as the `usemap=`

I have tried setting text-filtering to none, changing up the TinyMCE in the plugin manager etc... Thoughts?

Comment: Try going to `Global Configuration > Text Filters` and set the **Filter Type** to **No Filtering** for Public and Super Users

Comment: Already done.... I have No Filtering for everyone

Comment: what editor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem however with JCE (I am not using  TinyMCE)  bu I guess, this could help :

- in JCE / Edit Profile / Features and Layout: at the bottom : check the option "Adds support for OBJECT, EMBED, AUDIO, VIDEO and IFRAME elements. Required by the Media Manager and when inserting Adobe® Flash®, Quicktime® and other media file types"
- in JCE / Edit Profile / Editor parameters/advanced :  set all to yes
- in JCE / Edit Profile / Plugin parameters/media support  :  set all to yes

**This is what solve the problem for me :**

- Navigate to Content → Article Manager / Parameters (icon top right)
- Scroll down to Filtering Options, highlight all Filter groups except Super Administrator, and select Filter type of Blacklist

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the editor as No Editor in the Global Configurations and edit the article.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to: plugins/editors/tinymce
2. open tinymce.php
3. Find this

   Found this section:
   // advimage
   $advimage = $this->params->def('advimage', 1);
   if ($advimage)
   {
       $plugins[]  = 'advimage';
       $elements[] = 'img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name|style]';
   }
4. add |usemap after style, just like:

   // advimage
   $advimage = $this->params->def('advimage', 1);
   if ($advimage)
   {
       $plugins[]  = 'advimage';
       $elements[] = 'img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name|style|usemap]';
   }